# Why in python innermost for loop picks a different value from the one defined outside loop?

Tags: python, numpy

In the following code list value is after 0.2 interval. But when I print (h,i_sample) value in the inner most loop why h value is different from the one outside loop?How can I fix this error? If I create list with interval of 0.5 rather than 0.2 it picks correct values(same inside and outside the loops).

```
list =np.arange(1.0,5.0,0.2)
print(list)

for h in list:
    print("Loop: ", h)

    for i_sample in range(3):
        print(h,i_sample)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce, the values are the same. What exactly are you seeing, and what did you expect to see?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, reproducible with 2.7...

Comment: my list is [1.0,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,....4.8]. In first for loop when I print h value it is exactly same as in list but when I print h in the innermost loop instead of getting 1.6 I get 1.599999. Can you please give a simple explanation for this.

Comment: @user10163680, please read the duplicate.  It goes into detail on this.

Comment: @user10163680 the simplest explanation, floating point numbers are not exact representations, and when you print them, Python will try to show you "sensible" versions. Read the linked duplicate. If you *really* want to understand, read [this paper](https://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf)

Comment: That explanation is hard for me

Comment: The `print(list)` line displays the values rounded to a common precision.  `print(list.tolist())` will display the values in the full, ugly floating point detail.  There's no difference in values, just a difference in how they are displayed..

Comment: @user10163680, I understand the difficulty.  But it really is not simple.  If it were, people smarter than us would have fixed this long ago.  Best I can say is that you can either ignore it, or try really hard to study it enough to understand it .  Wish there was a better answer.

Comment: i got little bit idea that python is sensitive to the precision. I can do that by %.1f. But in this way I have to apply a for loop to get precision upto 1 decimal point. Can it be done without applying for loop

Comment: @user10163680 it's *not Python*, it's *binary floating point numbers*

Comment: Yes I can get precision by %.1f or %.3f

Comment: @user10163680 that is *string formatting*, that doesn't affect the `float` objects.

Comment: After formatting h value in this way I assign that h value to a variable but then I get error that np.float64 can not be interpreted as string. After string foramtting Does this value remain 1.59999